# Install CUDA 6.0 on Debian 7 via package manager

Tags: debian, drivers, nvidia, dependencies, cuda

I am following the [official installation guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html#ubuntu-installation) for Ubuntu. I first installed the [cuda-repo package](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads#linux) (`cuda-repo-ubuntu1304_6.0-37_amd64.deb`), which adds the NVIDIA repository to `apt`. Then it gives when installing that:

```
$ uname -a
Linux debian 3.14-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.14.10-1 (2014-07-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1304_6.0-37_amd64.deb
$ aptitude update
$ aptitude install cuda

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-settings : Depends: screen-resolution-extra (>= 0.12) which is a virtual package.
 nvidia-331 : Depends: xorg-video-abi-11 which is a virtual package. or
                       xorg-video-abi-12 which is a virtual package. or
                       xorg-video-abi-13 which is a virtual package. or
                       xorg-video-abi-14 which is a virtual package.
```

I cannot find any package named `screen-resolution-extra` via `aptitude search`. And there is only a `xorg-video-abi-15` in the repository which cannot be installed.

How can I solve this if I want to install CUDA via package manager?

Comment: Installing Ubuntu packages on a Debian system isn't such a good idea. Try this : https://wiki.debian.org/CUDA

Comment: @schaiba I have both an NVIDIA GT650M and an Intel HD 4000 on my laptop. Do I need to resort to bumblebee if I want to install the driver separately?

Comment: as far as I know, no. but my experience with bumblebee is fairly limited, so maybe someone else can answer.